# Crash on adding item while using QSorFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt

I have Custom treeview item model which works perfectly for adding and removing items (it passes QAbstractItemModelTester successfully).
Qt 6.7, Windows 10 64.

```
#include "ExampleTreeViewModel.h"
#include <QLocale>
#include "ExampleTreeViewItem.h"
#include <set>

template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
std::set<KeyType> getKeys(const std::map<KeyType, ValueType> &myMap)
{
    std::set<KeyType> keySet;
    for (const auto &pair : myMap) {
        keySet.insert(pair.first);
    }
    return keySet;
}

ExampleTreeViewModel::ExampleTreeViewModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractItemModel{parent}
{
    mRootItem = new ExampleTreeViewItem(88888, "Name", "Description");
}

QModelIndex ExampleTreeViewModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!mRootItem || row < 0 || column < 0 || column >= ColumnCount) {
        return QModelIndex();
    }
    auto *parentItem = getItemByModelIndex(parent);
    Q_ASSERT(parentItem);
    if (auto *item = parentItem->getChild(row)) {
        return createIndex(row, column, item);
    }
    return QModelIndex();
}

QModelIndex ExampleTreeViewModel::parent(const QModelIndex &child) const
{
    if (!child.isValid()) {
        return QModelIndex();
    }
    if (auto *childItem = getItemByModelIndex(child)) {
        if (auto *parentItem = childItem->getParent()) {
            if (parentItem == mRootItem) {
                return QModelIndex();
            }
            if (auto *grandParentItem = parentItem->getParent()) {
                int row = grandParentItem->getRowOfChild(parentItem);
                return createIndex(row, 0, parentItem);
            }
        }
    }
    return QModelIndex();
}

Qt::ItemFlags ExampleTreeViewModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::ItemFlags();

    return Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;
}

int ExampleTreeViewModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid() && parent.column() != 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return getItemByModelIndex(parent)->getChildrenCount();
}

int ExampleTreeViewModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return ColumnCount;
}

QVariant ExampleTreeViewModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()) {
        return QVariant();
    }

    switch (role) {
    case Qt::DisplayRole: {
        auto *item = getItemByModelIndex(index);
        QLocale aEnglish;
        switch ((Properties) index.column()) {
        case Properties::ExampleName:
            return item->getName();
        case Properties::ID:
            return item->getId();
        case Properties::Description: // description
        {
            return item->getPageFileUsage();
        }
        default:
            return QVariant();
        }
    }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

ExampleTreeViewItem *ExampleTreeViewModel::getItemByModelIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (index.isValid()) {
        if (auto *item = static_cast<ExampleTreeViewItem *>(index.internalPointer())) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return mRootItem;
}

void ExampleTreeViewModel::addItem(ExampleTreeViewItem *item, const QModelIndex &parentIndex)
{
    qDebug() << "AddItem: " << rowCount(parentIndex) << "\n";
    beginInsertRows(parentIndex, rowCount(parentIndex), rowCount(parentIndex));
    auto parentItem = getItemByModelIndex(parentIndex);
    parentItem->addChild(item);
    endInsertRows();
    mItemsById[item->getId()] = item;
}

void ExampleTreeViewModel::addItem(ExampleTreeViewItem *item, unsigned int parentItemId)
{
    auto *parentItem = mItemsById[parentItemId];
    item->setParent(parentItem);
    addItem(item);
}

void ExampleTreeViewModel::updateItem(int id, const QString &desciprtion)
{
    auto *item = mItemsById.at(id);
    item->setName(desciprtion);
    auto indices = getIndicesForRowByItem(item);
    if (!indices[0].isValid() || !indices[1].isValid()) {
        return;
    }
    emit dataChanged(indices[0], indices[1]);
}

bool ExampleTreeViewModel::itemExists(int id)
{
    return mItemsById.find(id) != mItemsById.end();
}
void ExampleTreeViewModel::deleteItem(unsigned int itemId)
{
    auto itemIt = mItemsById.find(itemId);
    if (itemIt != mItemsById.end()) {
        ExampleTreeViewItem *item = itemIt->second;
        auto parentItem = item->getParent();
        qsizetype row{parentItem->getRowOfChild(item)};
        beginRemoveItems(parentItem, row, row);
        parentItem->takeChild(row);

        std::vector<int> childIds = getChildrenIds(item);
        for (int childId : childIds) {
            auto childItemIt = mItemsById.find(childId);
            if (childItemIt != mItemsById.end()) {
                auto *childItem = childItemIt->second;
                mItemsById.erase(childId);
                qDebug() << "Erased from map " << childId;
                delete childItem;
            }
        }
        mItemsById.erase(item->getId());
        qDebug() << "Erased from map " << item->getId();

        delete item;
        endRemoveItems();
    }
}

void ExampleTreeViewModel::addItem(ExampleTreeViewItem *item)
{
    ExampleTreeViewItem *parentItem = item->getParent();
    if (parentItem == nullptr) {
        parentItem = mRootItem;
    }
    if (parentItem) {
        if (parentItem->hasChild(item->getId())) {
            return;
        }
        qsizetype rowToStartInsertingAt{parentItem->getChildrenCount()};
        qsizetype rowToEndInsertingAt{rowToStartInsertingAt};
        if (parentItem != mRootItem) {
            qDebug() << parentItem->getId() << " " << item->getId()
                     << ": inserting for children count " << parentItem->getChildrenCount() << "at "
                     << rowToStartInsertingAt << "\n";
            auto insertBegins = beginInsertItems(parentItem,
                                                 rowToStartInsertingAt,
                                                 rowToEndInsertingAt);
            parentItem->addChild(item);
            if (insertBegins) {
                endInsertItems();
            }
        } else {
            qDebug() << parentItem->getId() << " " << item->getId()
                     << ": inserting for children count " << parentItem->getChildrenCount() << "at "
                     << rowToStartInsertingAt << "\n";
            beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowToStartInsertingAt, rowToEndInsertingAt);
            parentItem->addChild(item);
            endInsertRows();
        }
        mItemsById.at(item->getId()) = item;
    }
}

QModelIndex ExampleTreeViewModel::getIndexByItem(ExampleTreeViewItem *item) const
{
    auto it = mItemsById.find(item->getId());
    if (it != mItemsById.end()) {
        auto parent = it->second->getParent();
        parent = parent ? parent : mRootItem;
        int row = parent->getRowOfChild(it->second);
        if (row != -1) {
            return createIndex(row, 0, item);
        }
    }
    return QModelIndex();
}

std::array<QModelIndex, ExampleTreeViewModel::ColumnCount>
ExampleTreeViewModel::getIndicesForRowByItem(ExampleTreeViewItem *item) const
{
    auto it = mItemsById.find(item->getId());
    if (it != mItemsById.end()) {
        int row = it->second->getParent()->getRowOfChild(it->second);
        return {createIndex(row, 0, item),
                createIndex(row, ColumnCount - 2, item),
                createIndex(row, ColumnCount - 1, item)};
    }
    return {QModelIndex(), QModelIndex()};
}

bool ExampleTreeViewModel::beginInsertItems(ExampleTreeViewItem *parentItem,
                                            int rowToStartInsertingAt,
                                            int rowToEndInsertingAt)
{
    QModelIndex parentIndex = getIndexByItem(parentItem);
    if (parentIndex.isValid()) {
        qDebug() << "beginInsertItems: " << rowCount(parentIndex) << " " << rowToStartInsertingAt
                 << "\n";
        beginInsertRows(parentIndex, rowToStartInsertingAt, rowToEndInsertingAt);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void ExampleTreeViewModel::endInsertItems()
{
    endInsertRows();
}

void ExampleTreeViewModel::beginRemoveItems(ExampleTreeViewItem *parent, int first, int last)
{
    QModelIndex idx = getIndexByItem(parent);
    beginRemoveRows(idx, first, last);
}

void ExampleTreeViewModel::endRemoveItems()
{
    endRemoveRows();
}

std::vector<int> ExampleTreeViewModel::getChildrenIds(ExampleTreeViewItem *item)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (const auto child : item->getChildren()) {
        result.push_back(child->getId());
        getChildrenIdsRecursive(child, result);
    }
    return result;
}
void ExampleTreeViewModel::getChildrenIdsRecursive(const ExampleTreeViewItem *item,
                                                   std::vector<int> &ids)
{
    for (const auto child : item->getChildren()) {
        ids.push_back(child->getId());
        getChildrenIdsRecursive(child, ids);
    }
}

void ExampleTreeViewModel::updateMapOfExampleess(
    std::map<unsigned int, ExampleInfo> &exampleInfoRecords)
{
    std::set<int> difference;
    auto oldKeys = getKeys(mItemsById);
    auto newKeys = getKeys(exampleInfoRecords);
    std::set_difference(oldKeys.begin(),
                        oldKeys.end(),
                        newKeys.begin(),
                        newKeys.end(),
                        std::inserter(difference, difference.begin()));
    for (auto exampleIdToDelete : difference) {
        deleteItem(exampleIdToDelete);
    }

    for (auto &[exampleId, pi] : exampleInfoRecords) {
        // qDebug() << "Filling " << exampleId << "("<< pi.parentExampleId << ")" << "\n";
        auto existintgTreeItemIt = mItemsById.find(exampleId);
        if (existintgTreeItemIt != mItemsById.end()) {
            auto &existingItem = *existintgTreeItemIt->second;
            existingItem.setName(QString::fromStdWString(pi.name));
            existingItem.setDescription(QString::fromStdWString(pi.description));
            existingItem.setWorkingSetSize(pi.extendedInfo.memoryInfo.WorkingSetSize);
            existingItem.setPageFileUsage(pi.extendedInfo.memoryInfo.PageFileUsage);

            auto time = pi.perfData.frequency100Ns - existingItem.getFrequency();
            if (time != 0) {
                auto cpu = pi.perfData.percentExampleorTime - existingItem.getPercentage();
                double ratioPerCpuInPercents{double(cpu) / time / m_exampleorCount * 100};
                double cpuUsage{std::roundf(ratioPerCpuInPercents * 100) / 100.0};

                if (existingItem.getId() != 0) {
                    mItemsById.at(0)->setCpuUsage(mItemsById.at(0)->getCpuUsage() - cpuUsage);
                }

                existingItem.setCpuUsage(cpuUsage);
            }
            existingItem.setPercentage(pi.perfData.percentExampleorTime);
            existingItem.setFrequency(pi.perfData.frequency100Ns);
        } else // item is new
        {
            auto newItem = new ExampleTreeViewItem(pi.id,
                                                   QString::fromStdWString(pi.name),
                                                   QString::fromStdWString(pi.description));
            if (!pi.executablePath.empty()) {
                //     auto imageIt = exampleesPixmaps.find(pi.executablePath);
                //     if (imageIt != exampleesPixmaps.end())
                //     {
                //         newItem->setIcon(*imageIt);
                //     }
                //     else
                //     {
                //         SHFILEINFO shfi;
                //         SHGetFileInfo(pi.executablePath.c_str(), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &shfi,
                //                       sizeof(shfi), SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES| SHGFI_LARGEICON| SHGFI_SMALLICON);
                //         if (shfi.hIcon != nullptr)
                //         {
                //             QImage image(QImage::fromHICON(shfi.hIcon));
                //             newItem->setIcon(image);
                //             exampleesPixmaps.insert(pi.executablePath, image);
                //         }
                //     }
            }
            // newItem->setExecutablePath(QString::fromStdWString(pi.executablePath));
            newItem->setPercentage(pi.perfData.percentExampleorTime);
            newItem->setFrequency(pi.perfData.frequency100Ns);
            mItemsById[pi.id] = newItem;
        }
    }
}

QVariant ExampleTreeViewModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        return PropertiesNames.at((ExampleTreeViewModel::Properties) section);
    }
    return QVariant();
}

void ExampleTreeViewModel::load(std::map<unsigned int, ExampleInfo> &exampleInfoRecords)
{
    //Create tree of examplees. Item are being added or updated if already exist. Parents are not set here.
    updateMapOfExampleess(exampleInfoRecords);

    // set parents for all existing items
    for (auto &[exampleId, pi] : exampleInfoRecords) {
        auto &childItem{mItemsById.at(exampleId)};
        if (exampleId != 0) {
            if (auto foundParent = mItemsById.find(pi.parentExampleId);
                foundParent != mItemsById.end()) {
                bool containsChild = foundParent->second->hasChild(exampleId);
                if (!containsChild) {
                    addItem(childItem, pi.parentExampleId); //
                }
            } else // if parent is non-existent example
            {
                addItem(childItem);
            }
        } else // example id = 0 is always top level example
        {
            if (!mRootItem->hasChild(exampleId)) {
                childItem->setParent(mRootItem);
                addItem(childItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to sort and filter, so I use QSortFilterProxyModel-base model:

```
ExampleTreeFilterModel::ExampleTreeFilterModel(QObject *parent) : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
    setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(true);
}

bool ExampleTreeFilterModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const
{
    switch (static_cast<ExampleTreeViewModel::Properties>(left.column())) {
    case ExampleTreeViewModel::Properties::ID: {
        auto model = static_cast<ExampleTreeViewModel *>(sourceModel());
        auto children = model->children();
        auto l = model->getItemByModelIndex(left);
        auto r = model->getItemByModelIndex(right);
        return l->getId() < r->getId();
    }

    default:
        return QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(left, right);
    }
}

bool ExampleTreeFilterModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    if (!sourceParent.isValid()) {
        return true;
    }
    // check the current item
    bool result{_searchStrings.empty()};
    for (const auto &[key, value] : _searchStrings) {
        QModelIndex currntIndex = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow,
                                                       static_cast<int>(key),
                                                       sourceParent);
        auto model = sourceModel();
        auto item = model->data(currntIndex, Qt::DisplayRole).value<QString>();
        auto contains = item.contains(value, Qt::CaseInsensitive);
        result = result || contains;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem is when I add an item I get

> ASSERT: "first <= rowCount(parent)"

although in source model for example child count is 2 and first = 2, I suspect that index is not map properly in proxy model.

Should I override `mapToSource` somehow in my proxy model?

**Update**
The reason why I chose to use QAbstractProxyModel-based custom implementation is because it is in many tutorials on how to sort and filter.

So I want to filter items by item properties by typing text in a textfield (say, somewhere above the treeview).
I want to select by what property I want to filter by combobox (by Id, By Name, everywhere)
Regarding sorting: some properties are numeric, and some are string ones. I want them to be sorted by clicking on a corresponding column header.

Comment: Was there really a good reason to make a subclass of `QSortFilterProxyModel`? What is your **detailed** goal with it?

Comment: When creating custom models, always test them using  https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodeltester.html

Comment: @hyde I write that I use QAbstractItemModelTester

Comment: @Atmo I want to filter and sort. Can I avoid the use of QSortFilterProxyModel?

Comment: Yeah... read my question again maybe? And please **edit** your question with details.

Comment: @Atmo Please check the update, I hope I clarified it a bit.

Comment: Let me put it this way then: does it crash when you use a `QSortFilterProxyModel` instead of your `ExampleTreeFilterModel`?

Comment: @Atmo yes, it does

Comment: Then the issue is most likely **not** with the proxy model, is it? Which in turns means you have some debugging to do so that you can share what line in your code makes it crash. This is not something we can do for you.

Comment: @Atmo Yes, but it passes QAbstractItemModelTester successfully.

Comment: That is something you have written in your question already, and I made my comment knowing that. Obviously, the fact it passes these tests does not mean the model is perfect. 1 example: in `addItem`, you call your method `beginInsertItems` (why not directly `beginInsertRows`?), then **regardless of the result**, you insert the item, and only then you check the result to know if you must call `endInsertItems` (again, why don't you make it easier for everyone to read and help you by simply using `endInsertRows`). So you may end up inserting a row without ever emitting the signals...

Comment: Cont'd In `beginInsertItems`, we learn that you have decided not to emit signals when the inserted item is a direct child of `mRootItem` (BTW, it takes a lot of reading, browsing up and down, to link these pieces together; your code definitely is **not** an MRE) but there is no comment about why. AFAICT, you implement of `rowCount` just returns a list count without caring if the `parent` you are looking at is the root so I do not see how a proxy model could make sense of its source model suddenly having an additional row in that case...

Comment: Finally: the reason why I say this code is not an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is not simply because of these extra functions, it is also a matter of having unused methods (e.g. `updateItem` is called nowhere, so should not have been included), keeping the full definition for methods that are unrelated to the issue (I do not see `data` having any impact, so its definition could have been replaced by a simple `return QVariant()` to save us some scrolling) and not providing the header+main files to allow us to reproduce.